# C++ Sum of numbers inserted by the user less than 10billion

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

So I've been trying to make a program that counts number of digits entered by a user as long as the value is less than 10 billion, but I can't seem to get it to work properly. So far it counts the number of digits entered but it does not recognise if the value is greater or less than 10 billion instead it just ignores the loop in the code and prints out "10" for every value entered that's greater than 10 billion. I've tried everything I can think of (I'm pretty new to programming and all so excuse my errors if any). :C

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(){
long n;
cout<<"Enter a number less than 10billion:";
cin>>n;

if (( n>=10000000000 || ( n<-0 ))) {

    cout<< endl <<"Number exceeds the range"<< endl;
}
else{
int count=0;
while(n>0){

    n=n/10;
    count++;

}
cout<<"Total number of digits="<<count;

return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: use a string, then "counting" is really just counting

Comment: On some system (like e.g. Windows using the Visual C++ compiler) the type `long` is still a 32-bit signed type. And thus can't hold such large values. If you want a guaranteed 64-bit type, use e.g. `int64_t` (or in your case since you don't want negative numbers, `uint64_t`, and don't forget to make sure the input was successful).

Comment: Change `long n;` to `double n;`.

Comment: Please show you input. I assume you entered a huge number that overflows `MAX_LONG` and got a negative number in `n`. Use a debugger to watch `n`.

Comment: @Eljay That is a terrible idea.  You can `%` a `double`.  `int64_t` or `long long` will work for the OP

Comment: user463035818 is absolutely right. Just use `getline (cin, mystr);` and `cout << mystr.size() << endl;` and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the assist guys. @some programmer dude your fix worked like a charm :D